# How far out is too far for a start date?

Tags: professionalism, start-date, transition

So I am currently employed at an Information Technology/ Help Desk internship through my school's work study program, and in order to make my transition out as smooth as possible, my boss has asked me to train my replacement for (ideally) a month. I have no real problem doing this, as I am not located far from either work or school and the person I had in mind to replace me is a friend of mine.

However, the process of actually transitioning out is a little more complicated. I do not have another job secured per se, but I can continue to tutor at the school at the same hours and pay until I graduate. Since I'd rather not be without the money, I'm thinking the best way to do this is leave the internship early, help train the replacement, and tutor until I can find a job.

This seems to be the safest back-up option to me, but I would like to start interviewing ASAP. So my question then is this: **Suppose I interview well and manage to get an offer in the same week as I begin training my replacement. Would I be unreasonable in proposing a start date a month out?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Suppose I interview well and manage to get an offer in the same week
>   as I begin training my replacement. Would I be unreasonable in
>   proposing a start date a month out?

A month out will almost certainly not be a problem. **It would be very reasonable to propose that sort of delay in starting if it is needed.**

In my experience, managers hiring folks who have yet to graduate will expect that they may need to wait a while before the candidate can start. I have seen offers extended to candidates who weren't graduating for months.

Even for folks who have been in the workforce, a month is not unreasonable at all. I expect anyone I make an offer to will need to give at least 2 weeks notice, and I've often had candidates tell me that they wanted to take a vacation between jobs.

You may get lucky and land a job right away, but it would be far more typical for it to take a while to land an offer for a job that suits you well.

Start looking for your job, and don't be worried about the start date yet. These things have a way of working themselves out.